# this.items.slice is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Hi I am learning vue with vuetify and I am trying to get users from backend api with Axios.

The problem is that I am getting this.items.slice is not a function error

This is what I tried inside my index.vue page

```
<script>
  /* import { Items as Users } from '@/api/user' */

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        search: '',
        users:[],
        complex: {
          selected: [],
          headers: [
            {
              text: 'Avatar',
              value: 'avatar'
            },
            {
              text: 'Name',
              value: 'name'
            },
            {
              text: 'Email',
              value: 'email'
            },
            {
              text: 'Phone',
              value: 'phone'
            },
            {
              text: 'Action',
              value: ''
            }
          ]
          /* items: Users */
        }
      }
    },
    async asyncData({ $axios }) {
      const users= await $axios.$get('http://localhost:3333/api/users')
      return { users}
    }
  }
</script>
```

I am expecting to get users in table, I have check the api in postman and I get the correct response with all users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, remove users from your data function:

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        search: '',
        // users:[], delete this line
        complex: {
...
```

You shouldn't have what you want asyncData to return in your data function. asyncData will put it there itself.

Then try your asyncData like this:

```
async asyncData () {
    let { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3333/api/users')
    return { users: data.users } //or however your 'data' comes back. Try console.log(data) to see.
  }
```

The way you are currently returning 'users' would be a more complex object than just the users data so you should change it to return only the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have courses property iin data object.  add courses/users property in the return data object. Anyway I'll suggest to do it like that:  add a methods property there add your asynData function to get the async info.  Add created life cycle and there do this.courses=this.asyncData().

Comment: I tried adding    courses: [], to data return but its still the same error

Answer (score 0):

You seem to request for `users` with the API `http://localhost:3333/api/users`, however, you're setting the data variable name as `courses`, which is also being used in the template.

So, I'm guessing the issue is with the way you're trying to display inside the template. Could you share a CodeSandbox or a repo so that we could have a better understanding of your problem?

Thanks!

Edit:
Axios usually returns with a `response` object which looks something like:

```
{
  status: 200,
  data: {/*some object */}
}
```

Maybe you need to do something like:

```
      const response = await $axios.$get('http://localhost:3333/api/users')
      console.log(response); // Just to check what response looks like
      return { users: response.data }
```

Comment: Yes it is named courses , should be users my mistake. But that is not the issue here. I renamed it to users.

Comment: @Stacey: Have a look at the updated response above.